# Silverstripe MAMP Pro: get_magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php, silverstripe, php-ini

I'm trying to install Silverstripe 3.1.1 on my local machine running MAMP Pro. I'm getting the error:

> Warning: get_magic_quotes_gpc support is being removed from
>   Silverstripe. Please set this to off in your php.ini and see
>   http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php in
>   xxxxxxxxxx/framework/core/Constants.php
>   on line 142

I'm running PHP 5.3.6 I've checked my php ini file and there is no reference to this. There is a magic_quotes_sybase which is set to off.

If I run PHP 5.2.17 I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in
>   xxxxxxxxxxxx/framework/main.php
>   on line 117

In the 5.2.17 php.ini file I have a setting for magic_quotes_gpc (not get_magic_quotes_gpc). I get the above error regardless of wether this is set to on or off.

I do not get the option to proceed with the installation ignoring the error. Just the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you need 2 files (.htaccess & php.ini) to turn off magic_quotes_gpc,

1. add entry of the top of .htaccess file

SetEnv PHPRC /home/limecoke/public_html/php.ini

1. create php.ini and add below code

magic_quotes_gpc = Off

---

also make your php version 5.3,2

if php version is below 5.3.2 it generates

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in xxxxxxxxxxxx/framework/main.php on line 117

Answer (score 0):

You can have local php.ini files in your folders to change settings for just those folders, rather than system wide.

Create a `php.ini` file in the root Silverstripe directory. Also place one in your framework directory. In the php.ini file add the following text:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = 0
```